# InitializeComponent method for 3CX dialer

Tags: c#, 3cx

I am to fix the dialer for 3CX in the company where I work which was designed by some other colleague.

Asking here and there I found out I can reverse engineer the CFD compiler script which is in C# back into an actual Call Flow Designer project to build what it does, so I can see which components have been used and customize the bit I need to work to accomplish the new features we want for our software.

So far so good, but what actually means to read the InitializeComponent method to replicate what the dialer does? How do I do it?